# Двоичное представление строки

Tags: matlab

Как правильно получить двоичный код строки, полученной при чтении из текстового фала? Это требуется для последующего кодирования.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `dec2bin(x)`, `double(S)` - преобразует символы строки S в числовые коды 0-65535 и возвращает вектор с этими числовыми кодами.